# How do Google APIs pickle files work in Python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, pickle, google-api-python-client

I´m starting with Google APIs and I have copied [this code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) which is a quickstart sample.
The program runs perfectly, but I would like to investagate the `token.pickle` file which the code generates.

I have made a little program to view the content of that file.

```
import pickle

pickle_in = open("token.pickle","rb")
example_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)

print(example_dict)
dir(example_dict)
```

But when I run it I, the output is this:

```
<google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object at 0x0000027365C72F08>
<<<<BLANK SPACE>>>>>
```

I understand the first part of the output, but no the second one. I mean: if there is nothing on that file, how does it work?

**EDIT**

When I open the file with notepad, the text is this:

```
    €cgoogle.oauth2.credentials
    Credentials
    q )q}q(X   tokenqX²   gttgtgtgtgtp0P_FZqgFEuiEvRkAB4e3NrVCZM9lal5LygHt631futEx-okxN7VEg_SfnIwFycqX   expiryqcdatetime
    datetime
    qC
    ä
    2
     ‹q…qRq X   _quota_project_idq
    NX   _scopesq]qX7   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonlyq
    aX   _refresh_tokenqXg   1//03FdAxjcGOfLrCgYIARAAGAMSNwF-L9IrbE19bft-Aug6LL5g8NEC1vhH_y6alnPXpQ6G4M5H5ti3RIk6M3SGFvCQF8OfqwLvUe8qX     _id_tokenqNX
       _token_uriqX#   https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokenqX
       _client_idqXH   2hytgtg000o0000000l36ut0uet

f9l42u7bd59.apps.googleusercontent.comqX   _client_secretqX   "client secret".
```

Comment: try `for i in example_dict: print(i)` and `print(example_dict.__dict__)` Also ensure that you close the root file after `pickle.load`

Comment: TypeError: 'Credentials' object is not iterable